# Let $V$ be a vector space and $\dim(V) ≥ 2$. How to prove with that information that there exists three points that are not on the same line?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $\dim(V) ≥ 2$. How to prove with that information that there exists three points that are not on the same line?

I understand how to normally prove that in a vector space there exists three points that are not on the same line, but what does the $\dim(V)$ have to do with this?

Comment: If the dimension of your vector space was 1, how would you prove the statement?

Comment: try to think how you would prove it, and check if you need that restraint on the dimension. Geometrically, a 1-dimensional vector space is a line - that would make it difficult to find three points not on a line!

Comment: Since $\dim(V) \geq 2$, we can pick two vectors $V_1, V_2$ such that $V_1 \not \in \text{span}(V_2)$. Then $O, V_1, V_2$ are not colinear. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment by alxchen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927626/let-v-be-a-vector-space-and-dimv-%E2%89%A5-2-how-to-prove-with-that-information-that/2927856#comment6047792_2927626) already gives a short, very good proof.  I am offering an alternative.  I shall prove that, for any vector space $V$ over a field $K$, any three elements of $V$ are always collinear if and only if $$\dim_K(V)\in \{0,1\}\,.$$

The converse is trivial, so I am proving the direct implication.  Suppose that $V$ is a $K$-vector space in which three arebitrary elements of $V$ are on the same line.  If every element of $V$ is the zero vector, then $\dim_K(V)=0$.  Now, suppose that $V$ contains a nonzero vector $u$, i.e., $\dim_K(V)=1$.  Now, let $v\in V$ be arbitrary.  Since $0$, $u$, and $v$ are on the same line and $u\neq 0$, there exists $\lambda\in K$ such that
$$v-0=\lambda(u-0)\,.$$
That is, $v=\lambda u$.  Ergo, every element of $V$ is a scalar times $u$, whence $V$ is spanned by a nonzero element $u$.  This shows that $\dim_K(V)=1$.